# How to play Minecraft in retina resolution on a Macbook?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I was wondering if it was possible to play Minecraft in retina resolution on my Macbook Pro retina. The game seems to be a bit pixelated like some other applications do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could play Minecraft in retina resolution.

### OptiFine (Fullscreen only)

Using OptiFine you could play Minecraft in retina resolution by going to `Options...`, `Video Settings...`, `Other...` and set `Fullscreen Mode: default` to `Fullscreen Mode: (Resolution of screen)`. This should be achieved by pressing the button once. Now set `Fullscreen: OFF` to `Fullscreen: ON`. Your Minecraft should now be in retina resolution if it's in fullscreen.

### Custom resolution

An other option would be to change your resolution to the highest supported by the device. You can do this by downloading a 3th party application (I recommend Display Menu). Open this application and change your resolution to the highest resolution possible. To change it back, go to `System Settings`, and open `Display` and select default or any other resolution you want.

*Note: All other programs get scaled down*